# Log EL/JSP exceptions in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, el

I want to log the exception caused by EL (parsing/coercing to different type/NPE) or such other errors in JSP files into my tomcat logs.

Those are not logged automatically. What do I need to log those exceptions?

Comment: Do you know where your log file is? If you don't maybe the documentation can give you some hints ;) http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: I know where log files are but they don't EL errors by default and that's the point of question. Read the question again.

Answer (score 3):

I also struggled with this a long time. But I finally found out, that the jsp-errors are logged in the `localhost.<date>.log` file.

Tomcat creates several log files (maybe depending on your local configuration):

- `catalina.<date>.log`
- `host-manager.<date>.log`
- `localhost.<date>.log`
- `localhost_access_log.<date>.log`
- `manager.<date>.log`